# DropDownList com SelectedValue inválido porque não existe na lista de items

Tags: c#, asp.net

Não consigo entender o que esta mal. A DropDown esta em uma Formview de uma user control.
A dropDown liga a uma tabela de base de dados que deve retornar 2 valores id e nome

FormView

```
 <td><asp:DropDownList width="350px"
 ID="EntregaRegiaoDropDownList" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind ("Regiao") %>' DataSourceID ="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField ="RegiaoNome" DataValueField ="RegiaoID" Enabled ="False"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

Code behind  userControl.ascx

```
public bool Editable
{
    get 
    {
        if (ViewState["editable"] != null)
        {
            return (bool)ViewState["editable"];
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    set 
    {
        ViewState["editable"] = value;
    }
}
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    //Find o botao edit visible
    Button EditButton=
        FormView1 .FindControl ("EditButton") as Button;
    if (EditButton !=null )
    {
        EditButton .Visible =Editable ;
    } 
}
```

> DropDownList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not
> exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
> 'EntregaRegiaoDropDownList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid
> because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 30: {
>
> Line 31:         //Find o botao edit visible
>
> Line 32:         Button EditButton=
>
> Line 33:             FormView1 .FindControl ("EditButton") as Button;
>
> Line 34:         if (EditButton !=null )
>
> Source File: c:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio
>
> 2012\WebSites\BaumSGVO\UserControls\ClientesDetalhes.ascx.cs    Line:
> 32
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'EntregaRegiaoDropDownList' has a
> SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list
> of items. Parameter name: value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <td>
   <asp:DropDownList width="350px" ID="EntregaRegiaoDropDownList" runat="server"
     SelectedValue='<%# Bind ("Regiao") %>' //VALOR ATRELADO = REGIAO
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     DataTextField="RegiaoNome" 
     DataValueField="RegiaoID"              //VALOR DO VALUE = REGIAOID
     Enabled="False"></asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
```

Você deve usar a propriedade **SelectedValue** preferencialmente no momento de edição de um formulário, note que você seta o **DataValueField** como **RegiaoID** e no **SelectedValue** coloca apenas **Regiao**, isso torna impossível de a aplicação rodar pois está setando *campos diferentes*, coloque no **SelectedValue** como **RegiaoID** também e rode novamente que deve solucionar, agora para ter um melhor controle, sugiro que use a propriedade **SelectedValue** diretamente no codebehind.

Lembrando que só é possível selecionar o valor 'casando' os campos **RegiaoID = RegiaoID**.

> **ERRO:**
>    SelectedValue='<%# Bind ("Regiao") %>'

Comment: obrigada !!!!!consegui resolver o erro

Comment: Dei um `bind` antes de tentar pegar o `selectedvalue` e funcionou. Obrigado.